# Still trying to Close SLDS Dropdown Menu when clicked outside in Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning, slds

I am trying to solve the same problem as this question here -
[How to Close SLDS Dropdown Menu when clicked outside in Lightning Component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142549/how-to-close-slds-dropdown-menu-when-clicked-outside-in-lightning-component)

There does not seem to be an official answer for this question.

I am new to Stack Exchange so I can't comment on the other question, hence I am posting this question.

Does anyone have any new information regarding this issue?

I have tried the tabIndex="0" approach on the div -

```
<div tabIndex="0" onblur="{!c.exitMultiSelect}"  class="slds-combobox_container slds-p-left_xx-small slds-p-right_xx-small zslds-size_small">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Thanks for including a link to provide context. If you have any code, though, of what you've tried, could you please **[edit]** your question and include that code? Make sure you use the `{}` button to format your code for legibility.

Comment: I have tried using the tabIndex="0" onblur approach on the div in my component.  Thanks, I edited the code.

Comment: Hi, Can you clarify? Is it a custom lookup? Which shows another component as a drop-down. And you are trying to close it when clicked outside of this drop-down?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `onblur` event and `$A.util.toggleClass` or `$A.util.removeClass` like so:

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <div class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open" aura:id="myMenu">
        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:down" variant="border-filled" alternativeText="Show More" onclick="{!c.showHide}" onblur="{!c.hideOnBlur}"/>
        <div class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_left">
            <ul class="slds-dropdown__list" role="menu" aria-label="Show More">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item" indexVar="i">
                    <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="{!item.label}">{!item.label}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </aura:iteration>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

**Controller JS**

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        var options = [
            {'label': 'Label1', 'value': 'Value1'},
            {'label': 'Label2', 'value': 'Value2'},
            {'label': 'Label3', 'value':'Value3'}
        ];
        component.set("v.options", options);
        helper.showHide(component, event, helper);
    },

    showHide : function(component, event, helper){
        helper.showHide(component, event, helper);
    },

    hideOnBlur : function(component, event, helper){
        var myMenu = component.find('myMenu');
        $A.util.removeClass(myMenu, 'slds-is-open');
    },

})
```

**Helper JS**

```
({
    showHide : function(component, event, helper){
        var myMenu = component.find('myMenu');
        $A.util.toggleClass(myMenu, 'slds-is-open');
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated

```
    hideOnBlur : function(component, event, helper){
            var myMenu = component.find('myMenu');
        /*Without timeout Click function on the menu list won't trigger
       closes the menu before it could trigger */
       window.setTimeout(   
                $A.getCallback(function() {
                    $A.util.toggleClass(myMenu,'slds-is-open');
             }), 250);
```

Comment: I don't think that is really necessary. It worked for me without the timeout. But anyway, I am glad you got it to work!

Comment: yeah actually wrote an onclick event on values inside the menu without timeOut. It just closes and never triggers the onclick event.- you cool big thanks to you